# SQL - Trying to sum individual orders

Tags: sql

I have a database in which:

- 1 customer can place many orders
- 1 Order can contain many line items

the tables I have are

- Customers
- Orders
- Line Items

I want to generate a report that shows me the value of the Orders that have been billed by adding the Line Items.

When I try

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerNumber, Orders.OrderNumber, 
    SUM(LineItems.ItemPrice * LineItems.QuantityOrdered) AS 'Order Value'
FROM LineItems.ItemNumber
WHERE Customers.CustomerNumber = '1234'
GROUP BY Orders.OrderNumber, Customers.CustomerNumber
```

This seems to give me the individual orders but it gives me the total value of all orders the customer has placed.

Is there a way to show the value of each order individually not the sum of all orders placed?

### Update

```
SELECT
    Agreement.AgreementNumber AS 'Agreement Number', 
    POBase.PurchaseOrderNumber AS 'Purchase Order Number',
    SUM(POLI.UsedPrice * POLI.QuantityOrdered) AS 'Billed Amount'

FROM MyDatabase..PurchaseOrderLineItemBase AS POLI
INNER JOIN 
    MyDatabase..AgreementBase AS Agreement
    ON POLI.AgreementKey = Agreement.AgreementKey
INNER JOIN
    MyDatabase..PurchaseOrderBase AS POBase
    ON POLI.AgreementKey = POBase.AgreementKey
WHERE 
    (Agreement.AgreementNumber = '1234'
    OR Agreement.AgreementNumber =  '234')
    AND POLI.POLineItemStatusName = 'Invoiced'
GROUP BY 
    POBase.AgreementKey,
    POBase.PurchaseOrderNumber,
    Agreement.AgreementNumber
ORDER BY 
    Agreement.AgreementNumber
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query doesn't make sense, because you have tables listed that are not in the `from` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT o.CustomerNumber, o.OrderNumber, 
       SUM(li.ItemPrice * li.QuantityOrdered) AS 'Order Value'
FROM orders o JOIN
     LineItems li
     ON o.OrderNumber = li.OrderNumber
WHERE o.CustomerNumber = '1234'
GROUP BY o.OrderNumber, o.CustomerNumber;
```

Assuming that `CustomerNumber` is in the `Orders` table, you don't need the `CUstomers` table.

Comment: I thought this might happen. There is actually a good few tables involved, the DB is a nightmare. I am joining on other tables. I can post the whole query its just very long and drawn out!

Comment: You are missing a `join` condition between `PurchaseOrderLineItemBase` and `PurchaseOrderBase`.  You are confused because both seem to have some strange key, but they need to be joined on the equivalent of an order number.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, if you group by CustomerNumber it will do so. Get rid of the CustomerNumber in GROUP BY to get all the Orders.

Comment: the query groups by `OrderNumber` as well.

Comment: Yeah, but thats what he actually want.

Comment: So I get a when I remove the group by I get a whole host of other problems:

Comment: Well, thats another story. If you group by CustomerNumber, then the Database will merge EVERY row with the same CustomerNumber in ONE single row, thats not what you want. If you still have problems after removing CustomerNumber from the GROUP-BY then what do you get and what do you expect to geht, whats your actual query?

Comment: I get an error saying columns are not contained in either the aggregate function of the groupd by clause

Comment: @tkausl the query is grouping by `CustomerNumber` AND `OrderNumber,` so not all orders will be merged into a single `CustomerNumber`.

Comment: @Gek including `CustomerNumber` is not the problem -  you're filtering to only one CustomerNumber anyways and it's the simplest way to be able to include it in your `SELECT` list.

Comment: Think I might post the actual query above, its not really as simple as the above

Comment: Can you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with dummydata please? You're not joining correctly so your whole query just blows all up.

Comment: Query is above, have vhanged some of the names naturally